# Automate a search for members of the local 'Administators' group

Tags: list, powershell

I have a PowerShell script named script1.ps1 that work perfectly. Here is the script:

```
Write-Host Script to display members of the local -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host Administators group of a remote server. -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "`n"

$strComputer = Read-Host "Please enter the computer name"

$computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer")
$group = $computer.PSBase.Children.Find("administrators")

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Computer Name : "$computer.Name
Write-Host "_____________________________________"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Group Name : "$Group.Name
Write-Host "_____________________________________"

$domain = $group.Path.Split("/")[2]
$string1 = "WinNT://" + $domain + "/" + $strComputer + "/"
$string2 = $strComputer + "/"
$string3 = "WinNT://"

$members  = ($group.PSBase.Invoke("Members") | Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Adspath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -replace ($string1,$string2) -replace ($string3,"") 

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Members : "
Write-Host ""
$members
```

But as you can see, I'm obliged to write each time the name of computer I want.

I ask myself if there is a function or other things which take automatically the computers names from a text or CSV file?

Like this at the beginning of the script, it automatically take all the computers names & give me the members of the local 'Administators' group which then gonna be exported in one text file or CSV file too?

---

Updated script according to the answer given.

```
Write-Host Script to display members of the local -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host Administators group of a remote server. -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "`n"

Get-Content 'C:\Users\herbautr\Desktop\List1.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "-$_-"
  $computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $_ + ",computer")
  $group = $computer.PSBase.Children.Find("administrators")

  Write-Host ""
  Write-Host "Computer Name : "$computer.Name
  Write-Host "_____________________________________"
  Write-Host ""
  Write-Host "Group Name : "$Group.Name
  Write-Host "_____________________________________"

  $domain = $group.Path.Split("/")[2]
  $string1 = "WinNT://" + $domain + "/" + $_ + "/"
  $string2 = $_ + "/"
  $string3 = "WinNT://"

  $members  = ($group.PSBase.Invoke("Members") | Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Adspath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -replace ($string1,$string2) -replace ($string3,"") 

  Write-Host ""
  Write-Host "Members : "
  Write-Host ""
  $members
} | Set-Content 'C:\Users\herbautr\Desktop\administrators.txt'
```

I have add 1 computer name to the List1.txt:

```
01SPEAI-TEST1
01SPEAI-TEST2
02SPHPV-TEST1
01SLCPTAAP-PROD
```

And it works (not) perfectly (Unreadable layout)

```
01SPEAI-PROD1/Administrator
VNF-PRINCIPAL/Admins du domaine
VNF-PRINCIPAL/svceri
01SPEAI-PROD2/Administrator
VNF-PRINCIPAL/Admins du domaine
VNF-PRINCIPAL/svceri
02SPHPV-PROD1/Administrator
VNF-PRINCIPAL/Admins du domaine
01SLCPTAAP-PROD/Administrator
VNF-PRINCIPAL/Admins du domaine
01SLCPTAAP-PROD/maint
VNF-PRINCIPAL/svcoraas
VNF-PRINCIPAL/svcvisionit
VNF-PRINCIPAL/GopOAS
VNF-PRINCIPAL/svcdigora
```

Note (15:18pm): I have tried with 5 names, it continue to work.

Why when adding just 1 name it "works"?

Comment: Check that `$_` is what you think it is. What is the output of `Write-Host "-$_-"`?

Comment: @Ansgar Ok I see, I have made this check $_ = "lol"
Write-Host "$_" (displayed me lol) I understand. But should I define $_ before Get-Content or can I remplace $_ by what I want ?

Comment: You should put `Write-Host "-$_-"` inside your loop and report what the output is. Use the statement *exactly* as I put it here. Do not leave anything out. Do not add anything to it.

Comment: That is quite obviously *not* the output the loop would produce. Let's start over with something simple. Run the following command and update your question with its output: `cat 'C:\Users\herbautr\Desktop\List1.txt' | % { "-$_-" }`. Copy/paste the command. Copy/paste the output back.

Comment: @Ansgar I have add the command you gave me `cat 'C:\Users\herbautr\Desktop\List1.txt' | % { "-$_-" }` under the Get-Content command (?) and the result is the same as my post, it just add : `-01SPEAI-PROD1- -01SPEAI-PROD2- -02SPHPV-PROD1- -01SLCPTAAP-PROD- -01SLSPSSA-PROD1-` before `01SPEAI-PROD1/Administrator` (etc...)

Comment: You lost me. Does it work now, or does it not work? Are you still getting errors? For all input hostnames? Some of them?

Comment: Sorry ! It works with & without `Write-Host "-$_-"` , It just works since I have add 1 (or more) computers names into my `List1.txt`. I would have liked to understand why... and if you can tell me where should I set the layout ? Because in `administrators.txt` It sticks everything to one after the other that's horrible and unreadable =/

Comment: Replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output`. `Write-Host` writes directly to the host console. Its output can't be redirected or pipelined. See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Get-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\computers.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $_ + ",computer")
  ...
} | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\administrators.txt'
```

Note that you need to replace all occurrences of `$strComputer` inside the `ForEach-Object` loop with the current object [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) (`$_`).

If you want to use CSVs for input and output use the [`Import-Csv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and [`Export-Csv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) cmdlets.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\computers.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $_.ComputerName + ",computer")
  ...
  $members | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Member = $_
    }
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\administrators.csv' -NoType
```

Note that CSVs have some advantages when you need to handle items with multiple properties, but they require somewhat more elaborate handling than simple strings (as you can see in my example above).